# How to re-call an adapter procedure after session expiration?

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

While calling a protected procedure in an adapter (`getMyRecords`) and the server session is expired, the application re-login to get a new session, but it doesn't call `getMyRecords` again.

Below is a sample code:

**Adapter XML file**

```
<procedure name="getMyRecords" securityTest="appSecurityTest" />
```

**challengeHandler JS file**

```
    challengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof (response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined') {
            //Should enter automatically to handleChallenge but not always
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

After that this will execute the below code (**handle challenge**) :

```
    challengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {

        var hasGlobalHeader = (WL.Client.__getGlobalHeaders()['ENC-USER'] != undefined);

        if(hasGlobalHeader ){ //Re-login response

       //this will invoke the relogin procedure to get a new session and to authenticate the user

            challengeHandler.handleRelogin(response);                           
        }else{
            ...
        }

    };

    challengeHandler.handleRelogin = function(response){
        var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;
        if (authRequired == true) {
              var input = {
                        adapter: "AuthenticationAdapter",
                        procedure: "autoLogin",
                        parameters: [localStorage.getItem('encryptedUser'), lang]
                    };               

              WL.Client.invokeProcedure(input, {
                    onSuccess: function(response){
                        $logger.log('service :: autoLoginSuccess :: response : ', response);
                        def.resolve(response); 
                    }, 
                    onFailure: function(err){
                        $logger.log('service :: autoLoginFailure :: err : ', err);
                        def.reject(err); 
                    }
               }); 
        }else{              
            //InitContext
            initContext(response);
            goHome();               
            //challengeHandler.activeRequest = null ;
        }

    };
```

The problem is when calling submitSuccess it does not issue the original request but calls infinitely autoLogin procedure.

Comment: Please provide the implementation of that `handleRelogin` function.

Comment: I've edited my question, adding handleRelogin function implementation.

Comment: See my answer below. I don't see any reference to `submitSuccess`. Also your code seems to be using Promises, but I don't see where `def` is defined or used.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that for every time that `handleChallenge` is called, either `submitSuccess` or `submitFailure` is called.

Until you call one or the other, the framework does not know that you finished answering the challenge. Never leave a challenge unanswered.

Also I think that instead of:

`if (typeof (response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined') {`

You should try

`if (typeof (response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined' && response.responseJSON.authRequired == true) {`